# Don't know how to work IMU and NRF24 together

Tags: arduino-mega, mpu6050

I'm having problem  on how can I use IMU and NRF24 together.

This is the code that i'm trying to use,

```
 /*
 Copyright (C) 2012 James Coliz, Jr. <maniacbug@ymail.com>
 This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
 version 2 as published by the Free Software Foundation.

 Update 2014 - TMRh20
*/
/**
* Simplest possible example of using RF24Network 
*
* TRANSMITTER NODE
* Every 2 seconds, send a payload to the receiver node.
*/
#include <RF24Network.h>
#include <RF24.h>
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "I2Cdev.h"
#include "RTIMUSettings.h"
#include "RTIMU.h"
#include "RTFusionRTQF.h" 
#include "CalLib.h"


RTIMU *imu;                                           // the IMU object
RTFusionRTQF fusion;                                  // the fusion object
RTIMUSettings settings;                               // the settings object

//  DISPLAY_INTERVAL sets the rate at which results are displayed

#define DISPLAY_INTERVAL  300                         // interval between      
pose displays

//  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED defines the speed to use for the debug serial port

#define  SERIAL_PORT_SPEED  11520
unsigned long lastDisplay1;
unsigned long lastRate1;
int sampleCount1;




 RF24 radio(7,8);                    // nRF24L01(+) radio attached using    
 Getting Started board 
 RF24Network network(radio);          // Network uses that radio
 const uint16_t this_node = 01;        // Address of our node in Octal  
 format
 const uint16_t other_node = 00;       // Address of the other node in Octal   
 format
 const unsigned long interval = 2000; //ms  // How often to send 'hello   
 world to the other unit
 unsigned long last_sent;             // When did we last send?
 unsigned long packets_sent;          // How many have we sent already
 struct payload_t {                  // Structure of our payload
 unsigned long ms;
 unsigned long counter;
 };
 void setup(void)
 {
 int errcode;

 Serial.begin(SERIAL_PORT_SPEED);
 Wire.begin();
 imu = RTIMU::createIMU(&settings);                        // create the imu  
 object

 Serial.print("ArduinoIMU starting using device "); Serial.println(imu- 
 >IMUName());
 if ((errcode = imu->IMUInit()) < 0) {
 Serial.print("Failed to init IMU: "); Serial.println(errcode);
 }

 if (imu->getCalibrationValid())
    Serial.println("Using compass calibration");
 else
    Serial.println("No valid compass calibration data");

 lastDisplay = lastRate = millis();
 sampleCount = 0;

// Slerp power controls the fusion and can be between 0 and 1
// 0 means that only gyros are used, 1 means that only accels/compass are used
// In-between gives the fusion mix.

fusion.setSlerpPower(0.02);

// use of sensors in the fusion algorithm can be controlled here
// change any of these to false to disable that sensor

fusion.setGyroEnable(true);
fusion.setAccelEnable(true);
fusion.setCompassEnable(true);

Serial.println("RF24Network/examples/helloworld_tx/");

SPI.begin();
radio.begin();
network.begin(/*channel*/ 90, /*node address*/ this_node);
}
void loop() {

unsigned long now1 = millis();
unsigned long delta1;
int loopCount1 = 1;

while (imu->IMURead()) {                                // get the latest  
data if ready yet
// this flushes remaining data in case we are falling behind
if (++loopCount1 >= 10)
        continue;
    fusion.newIMUData(imu->getGyro(), imu->getAccel(), imu->getCompass(),   
imu->getTimestamp());
    sampleCount++;
    if ((delta1 = now1 - lastRate1) >= 1000) {
        Serial.print("Sample rate: "); Serial.print(sampleCount);
        if (imu->IMUGyroBiasValid())
            Serial.println(", gyro bias valid");
        else
            Serial.println(", calculating gyro bias");

        sampleCount = 0;
        lastRate1 = now1;
    }
    if ((now1 - lastDisplay1) >= DISPLAY_INTERVAL) {
        lastDisplay1 = now1;
     RTMath::display("Gyro:", (RTVector3&)imu->getGyro());                // gyro data
      RTMath::display("Accel:", (RTVector3&)imu->getAccel());              // accel data
      RTMath::display("Mag:", (RTVector3&)imu->getCompass());              // compass data
        RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose:", (RTVector3&)fusion.getFusionPose()); // fused output
       Serial.println();
    }
}

   network.update();                          // Check the network regularly

  unsigned long now = millis();              // If it's time to send a 
  message, send it!
  if ( now - last_sent >= interval  )
  {
  last_sent = now;
  Serial.print("Sending...");
  payload_t payload = { millis(), packets_sent++ };
   RF24NetworkHeader header(/*to node*/ other_node);
   bool ok = network.write(header,&payload,sizeof(payload));
  if (ok)
  Serial.println("ok.");
  else
  Serial.println("failed.");
  }
  }
```

My question is what  should I put in this part

```
   [code]struct payload_t {                  // Structure of our payload
    unsigned long ms;
    unsigned long counter;
    };
```

so that the output for

```
 RTMath::display("Gyro:", (RTVector3&)imu->getGyro());                //  
 gyro data
      RTMath::display("Accel:", (RTVector3&)imu->getAccel());                
 // accel data
      RTMath::display("Mag:", (RTVector3&)imu->getCompass());              
 // compass data
      RTMath::displayRollPitchYaw("Pose:", 
 (RTVector3&)fusion.getFusionPose()); // fused output[/code]
```

will Transmit to the RX ..

What will I put in this part :

```
   Serial.print("Sending...");
   payload_t payload = { millis(), packets_sent++ };
   RF24NetworkHeader header(/*to node*/ other_node);
   bool ok = network.write(header,&payload,sizeof(payload));
   if (ok)
   Serial.println("ok.");
   else
   Serial.println("failed.");
```

Please help me guys. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is what should I put in this part

You need to take the data from IMU sensor and put it into the payload. Remember that NRF24L01 allows max 32 byte payload and the library uses some of that.

The RTVector3 is a C++ class with 3 floating point numbers. With AVR float/double that is 12 bytes. This means that you will have to send several messages.

```
enum {
   GYRO_TYPE = 0,
   ACCEL_TYPE = 1,
   COMPASS_TYPE =2
};

struct payload_t {
  int8_t type;
  float data[3];
};
```

This assumes that the sender and receiver have the same data representation. The type field is for the value type (GYRO, ACCEL, COMPASS).

Cheers!

Comment: I tried it but there is an error, I don't know what will I put in the payload. , please see the edited code above. thank you :)